# Use result of AJAX call for FullCalendarEvents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I currently have this in my event drop:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CalendarServices.aspx/UpdateDrop",
    data: 'id=' + event.realid + '&start=' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '&resource=' + event.resource,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }
});
```

This is effectively 2 ajax calls. I could easily return events in my first ajax call and populate the calendar with them. Is there some way I could do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used and it worked:

```
eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay) {

    var id = event.id.toString();
    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    url = 'updateevent.php';
    alert (url);
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: {id:id, startDate:start},
    success: function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
        alert( "Success!" );
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
        alert( "Failed!" );
    }

     });
```

and this is my updateevent.php

```
<?php

//..... connection up top  

$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);

$id = $_POST['id'];
$startDate = $_POST['startDate'];

mysql_query("UPDATE ecc_events SET startDate= '$startDate' WHERE id= '$id' LIMIT 1; ");

?>
```